# Tropical polynomial Positivstellensatz

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

In real algebraic geometry, [Stengle's Positivstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stengle%27s_Positivstellensatz) can be used to characterize polynomials that are positive on a semialgebraic set.

Say that a *tropical semialgebraic set* is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by a finite sequence of tropical polynomial equations and tropical polynomial inequalities, or any finite union of these sets.

Given that so many theorems in algebraic geometry have a counterpart in tropical algebraic geometry, is there also a Positivstellensatz for characterizing *tropical semialgebraic sets*? 
Or something analog to Positivstellensatz in the tropical context?

If no, what are the main obstructions?

Answer (score 2):

http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~grigorev/pub/tropical_null.pdf

Tropical dual and primary effective Nullstellensaetze

http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~grigorev/pub/dim_np_completeness.pdf